# How to club awk and sed commands in bash

Tags: awk, sed

I having a file with three fields name,Rev_ration and sync which is :(colon delimeted) as shown below:

```
##Increase 
JOe:4.8:7

##Check as per revision 67
jonny:[5:9]:[7:0]
##Check as per revision 56
Salman:q[0:234]:5
```

Initially I am replacing the : which is in square brackets to !.
SecondlyExecuting my AWK.
Third I am replacing the ! which is in square brackets to :
I am trying below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/\([[0-9]\+\)!\([0-9]\+]\)/\1:\2/g' t5 >> t6
awk -F: '/^$/ /^#/ {c=$0; sub(/#+/,"", c); next} 
                {print $1,$2,"- message", "\"" c "\""}' t6 >> t7
sed 's/\([[0-9]\+\)!\([0-9]\+]\)/\1:\2/g' t7 >> t8

Getting syntax error
```

Above code is working fine but not able to ignore the empty lines

I need to get rid of empty lines inside the input file.

Desired output

```
JOe:4.8:7 - message "Increase "
jonny:[5:9]:[7:0] - message "Check as per revision 67"
Salman:q[0:234]: - message "Check as per revision 56"
```

How to club all three commands and how to get rid of empty lines.. How to fix that with the code shown above

Comment: @Kusalananda it got to know how to fix that issue but not able to remove empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

As it doesn't seem that you're actually doing anything with your `:`-delimited fields, we may concentrate on the lines starting with `##`, pick out the text from them, and insert the text on the following lines.

Using only `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^$/d; /^##/{ s///; h; d; }; G; s/\n\(.*\)/ - message "\1"/' file
JOe:4.8:7 - message "Increase "
jonny:[5:9]:[7:0] - message "Check as per revision 67"
Salman:q[0:234]:5 - message "Check as per revision 56"
```

The `sed` expression deletes empty lines with `/^$/d`.  It then saves any text after `##` into the hold space with `h` (after deleting the initial `##`, replacing whatever may be stored in the hold space already). For any other line that is not empty or a line that starts with `##`, it appends the text from the hold space with `G` and modifies it so that the added text is prefixed with  `- message "` and terminated by `"`.

Comment: In my above code itself how can I do that by ignoring the empty lines in AWK command because the input files which I am going to be used is some what different

Comment: @Kavitha Empty lines matches the regular expression `^$`. In `awk`, you could ignore empty lines with `/^$/ { next }`. My answer produces the correct result for your given text though, so if your _actual_ data looks different, please update the data in the question.

Comment: I add it with my above code but getting syntax error

Comment: @Kavitha Yes, because you forgot the `{ next }` bit. Also, if you update the code in the question, what's the point of the question?